# Resize Unity UI components on tablet

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have some UI elements like buttons and images, and they look OK on my mobile phone. However, when I run my game on 10' tablet, they are just too big. I would like to scale them a bit but also limit the max width and heigth. Is it possible in Unity 5?  I'm using C#.

Comment: Use anchors for that. Can you make screenshots wth one of this buttons selected?

Comment: What you are talking about is the very heart of Unity's (excellent) reactive layout.  https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui  here it is ...http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/comp-UIAutoLayout.html  Any reactive system from css to apple's autolayout in storyboard to Unity's system, takes time to master.  There are no quick solutions.  You will see many, many questions on here about specific problems.